# Insert date, calculated a function, in a calendar

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a calendar.

I fill the year and date like this
<<<<< Year >>>>>>
<<<<< month >>>>>>

By clicking on the arrow marks the year and month increase and decrease.

Now I have to fill the dates for the year and month selected.

I calculate the first day of month and last date of the month.

The dates must start filling from the first day.

If the first day is Thursday the date 1 must be on Thursday and the next days must follow that till the last date.

These are my functions in my controller

```
function phpcal()
    {
        $month=04;
        $day=01;
        $year=2010;
        echo date("D", mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year)); //here i am calculating the first day of the month
        echo '<br>lastdate'.date("t", strtotime($year . "-" . $month . "-01"));'' here i am calculating the lasdt date of the month
        //echo '<br>'.$date_end  = $this->lastOfMonth();
        $this->load->view('phpcal');
    }
function firstOfMonth($m1,$y1) 
{ 
           return date("m/d/Y", strtotime($m1.'/01/'.$y1.' 00:00:00')); 
} 
function lastOfMonth() 
{ 
           return date("m/d/Y", strtotime('-1 second',strtotime('+1                                                                month',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00')))); 
}
function phpcalview()
    {
        $year = $this->input->post('yearvv');
        $data['year'] = $this->adminmodel->selectyear();
        $data['date'] = $this->adminmodel->selectmonth();
        //print_r($data['date'] );

        $this->load->view('phpcal',$data); 
    }
```

This is my view page

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="1" bgcolor="#CCFFCC" align="center"  class="table_Style_Border">
<?  if(isset($date))
{
foreach($date as $row)
{?>


<tr>
    <td><?= $row['dbDate1'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate2'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate3'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate4'];?></td>     <td><?= $row['dbDate5'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate6'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate7'];?></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <td><?= $row['dbDate8'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate9'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate10'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate11'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate12'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate13'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate14'];?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?= $row['dbDate15'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate16'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate17'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate18'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate19'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate20'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate21'];?></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <td><?= $row['dbDate22'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate23'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate24'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate25'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate26'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate27'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate28'];?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?= $row['dbDate29'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate30'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate31'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate1'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate1'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate1'];?></td> <td><?= $row['dbDate1'];?></td>
</tr>

</tr>
<? }} ?>
</table>
```

How can I insert the dates starting from the day calculated in the function phpcal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a calendar script I partly wrote myself. It can check database data against a day and create a link. Take a look, maybe it's helpful:

```
// Start table
$display .= '<table class="calendar_table" border="0">';
// set the default timezone to use. Available since PHP 5.1
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
//This gets today's date
$date = time();
// Set the value to today
$today = date('d', $date);
//This will get the value from the url
if($_GET['month'] && $_GET['year']){
    $month = $_GET['month'];
    $year = $_GET['year'];
}else{
    //This puts the day, month, and year in seperate variables
    $day = date('d', $date);
    $month = date('m', $date);
    $year = date('Y', $date);
}
// Set values for previous and next month
$nextMonth = $month+1;
$previousMonth = $month-1;
// And for the year
$nextYear = $year;
$previousYear = $year;

// Check the month (there are only 12 so, fix)
if($month == '1'){
    $previousMonth = '12';
    $previousYear = $previousYear-1;
}elseif($month == '12'){
    $nextMonth = '1';
    $nextYear = $nextYear+1;
}

//Here we generate the first day of the month
$first_day = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year);

//This gets us the month name
$title = date('F', $first_day); 

//Here we find out what day of the week the first day of the month falls on
$day_of_week = date('D', $first_day);

//Once we know what day of the week it falls on, we know how many blank days occure before it. If the first day of the week is a Sunday then it would be zero
switch($day_of_week){
    case "Sun": $blank = 0; break;
    case "Mon": $blank = 1; break;
    case "Tue": $blank = 2; break;
    case "Wed": $blank = 3; break;
    case "Thu": $blank = 4; break;
    case "Fri": $blank = 5; break;
    case "Sat": $blank = 6; break;
}

//We then determine how many days are in the current month
$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year); 

// Get the url, check for home or module
if($_GET['pageName'] == 'Home'){
    $link_prefix = '?pageName=Home';
}else{
    $link_prefix = '?module=Agenda';
}

//Here we start building the table heads
$display .= "<tr class='calendar_header'><td class='calendar_navigation'><a href='".$link_prefix.'&month='.$previousMonth."&year=".$previousYear."' class=navigationLink>&lt;&lt;</a></td><td colspan='5' class='calendar_title_frontpage'> $title $year </td><td class='calendar_navigation'><a href='".$link_prefix.'&month='.$nextMonth."&year=".$nextYear."' class=navigationLink>&gt;&gt;</a></td></tr>";
$display .= "<tr class='calendar_weeks'><td class='calendar_weeks'>Zo</td><td class='calendar_weeks'>Ma</td><td class='calendar_weeks'>Di</td><td class='calendar_weeks'>Wo</td><td class='calendar_weeks'>Do</td><td class='calendar_weeks'>Vr</td><td class='calendar_weeks'>Za</td></tr>";

//This counts the days in the week, up to 7
$day_count = 1;

$display .= "<tr>";
//first we take care of those blank days
while ($blank > 0){
    $display .= "<td class='calendar_days'>&nbsp;</td>";
    $blank = $blank-1;
    $day_count++;
}

//sets the first day of the month to 1
$day_num = 1;

// Create query to get all the info from the database
$BlaatCms->DB->build(array('select' => 'id,dates,title,description','from' => 'calendar')); 


// Create array
$events = array();

// Getting the data from the database and put it in an array
while($calendar = $BlaatCms->DB->fetch($BlaatCms->DB->execute())){
    if(date('m', $calendar['dates']) == $month){
        $events[intval($BlaatCms->unixstamp_to_mmddyyyy($calendar['dates']))] .= '<a href="?module=Agenda&id='.$calendar['id'].'">'.date('d',$calendar['dates']).'</a>';
    }
}


//count up the days, untill we've done all of them in the month
while ($day_num <= $days_in_month){

    if(array_key_exists($day_num,$events)){
        if($day_num == $today && $month == date('m', $date) && $year == date('Y', $date)){
            $display .= "<td class='calendar_days_event_current'>".$events[$day_num]."</td>";
        }else{
            $display .= "<td class='calendar_days_event'>".$events[$day_num]."</td>";
        }

    }else{
        if($day_num == $today && $month == date('m', $date) && $year == date('Y', $date)){
            $display .= "<td class='calendar_days_current'>".$day_num."</td>";
        }else{
            $display .= "<td class='calendar_days'>".$day_num."</td>";
        }
    }

    $day_num++;
    $day_count++;

    //Make sure we start a new row every week
    if ($day_count > 7){
        $display .= "</tr><tr align=center>";
        $day_count = 1;
    }

} 

//Finaly we finish out the table with some blank details if needed
while ( $day_count >1 && $day_count <=7 ){
    $display .= "<td class='calendar_days'>&nbsp;</td>";
    $day_count++;
}

$display .= "</tr>";

// Show link to nieuws archive
$display .= '<tr><td colspan="7" class="calendar_readmore_frontpage"><a href="?module=Agenda">'.$agenda_config['textOverview'].'</a></td>';

$display .= "</table>";
// Echo the table
echo $display;
```